# Binding Combobox SelectedValue to Textbox

Tags: wpf, data-binding, combobox, textbox

I have a `TextBox` and a `ComboBox`.  I want to bind `ComboBox` the selected value to text in the `TextBox`.

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

```
<ComboBox x:Name="MyComboBox">
  <ComboBoxItem>12</ComboBoxItem>
  <ComboBoxItem>13</ComboBoxItem>
  <ComboBoxItem>14</ComboBoxItem>
  <ComboBoxItem>15</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=SelectedValue.Content, ElementName=MyComboBox}" />
```

Since the items in the `ComboBox` are of type `ComboBoxItem`, I used the `Content` property to get the *real* value. You should use whatever property exposed by the objects in your `ComboBox` (use nothing if it already is a list of strings).

Answer (score -1):

This is for a listbox, not a combobox, but it should be pretty much the same code:

```
private void *lstProducts*_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    *currentlabel*.Content = *lstProducts*.SelectedValue.ToString();
}
```

The italicized bits are the names of the control.

Hope it helps...